# Store image in side a folder from JS Reference

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-storage

I can write and read an image from Firebase Storage but not how I want!

Im aiming to save images to a folder in firebase storage which should follow "Workout Images" -> users uid -> file name.

But I can't seem to creat this root and instead the image only saves as workout image in the main section of the storage and rewrites every time.

I thought adding the / would create the folders as I've seen in other answers.

```
document.getElementById("saveExplorePost").addEventListener("click", function savetPostWorkout() {

     const fileButton = document.getElementById("exerciseImage");
     const file = fileButton.files[0];
     const storageRef = ref(storage, "Workout Images/",  uid/ file.name);

     const exploreText = document.getElementById("exploreText").value
               
     uploadBytes(storageRef, file).then((snapshot) => {
          console.log('uploaded successfully');

               //collects the image download url
          getDownloadURL(ref(storage, "Workout Images/", uid/ file.name))
               .then((url) => {

                    console.log("downloadURL", url);
                    const postExploreImage = doc(db, "explore", randomID);
                    const userProfileRef = onSnapshot(doc(db, "uuid", uid), (doc) => {
                    
                         const Docid = doc.id;
                         const User = doc.data().user;

                    setDoc(postExploreImage, {
                                  
                         image: url,
                         title: exploreText,
                         user: User,
                         date: currentDate,
 
                    }, { merge: true }).then(function () {
                         console.log("Saved");

                              window.location = '../explore.html';      

                    }).catch(function (error) {
                       console.log("Error: ", error);   

                    });
               });
          });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter when using `ref` should be a full path of the file including the file name. I'm also using template literals because they allow embedding variables within a string.

```
//generate a random id
const uid = crypto.randomUUID() 

// Create a firebase storage reference    
const storageRef = ref(storage, `WorkoutImages/${uid}/${file.name}`);
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) for further information.

Comment: I've tried that, I couldn't get the ${""} part to work. it never connected to what it was attached to and instead just got saved as ${uid} in storage

Comment: The uid variable must exist inorder for ${uid} to work. I have updated the answer to show an example of generating a random id. But you can use a package of your choice to do the same.

Comment: Was using ' instead for `

Comment: Template literals only work with backticks ` `